# multiple AD domains

Tags: 2013

We have multiple AD domains in the enterprise due to mergers and acquisitions. We now have managers and employees under the manager working in different domains.

Is there a solution for this where I can have AD1\User1 and make his manager AD3\Mngr2?

We currently bring all people into User Profiles but the organisational browser cannot display a manager in a different AD to the current profile being used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is by design with the UPSS. It's not possible to do cross-forest manager attributes due to the manager attribute being a DN. Because SharePoint doesn't recognize cross-forest objects (where they're a foreign security principal in the local domain), it's not possible to import managers across forests.